# How to specify a file path in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io

I want to specify a virtual path of a file but I am not able to do so.

Here is my code:

```
int Course_Id = 1;
int PortfolioID=1;
int ChandidateID=1;

string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/ePortfolio/PortFolioContent/" + Course_Id + "/Assignments/Exhb_" + item.PortfolioID + "_" + item.ChandidateID + ".jpg");

if(System.IO.File.Exists((filepath)))
{                            
    ViewBag.Thumbnail = filepath;
}
```

When i use Server.MapPath it is fetching data from some other path:
My original path is:
E:\HOBBYHOMES(E-PORTFOLIO)\HobbyHomesWebApp\ePortfolio\PortFolioContent\1\Assignments
but it is taking this path
E:\HOBBYHOMES(E-PORTFOLIO)\HobbyHomesWebApp\ActivityPostin\Images\ePortfolio\PortFolioContent\1\Assignments\Exhb_1_1.jpg
I m not understanding why this is workin so.Please help me

Comment: I don't have a good solution for you, but here is why what you've tried so far doesn't work. I don't think ~ expands to anything in filepaths on Windows--some command shells do that but not the filesystem itself. '..' is going to be based on the current working directory (which is likely the directory of the executable you are running, or something equally useless).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/... ...jpg");`

Comment: hey thanx 4 d reply..i used ur method but still the prob is nt resolved.Please see i hav updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Url.Content("~/Content/Images/YourImageName.png")

Comment: hey thanx 4 d reply but wats the problem with this path..act i am bound to use this path only

Comment: Your are going for the following path






string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/ePortfolio/e-Portfolio/PortFolioContent/" + Course_Id 
           + "/Assignments/Exhb_" + PortfolioID + "_" + ChandidateID + ".jpg");

1) E:\HOBBYHOMES(E-PORTFOLIO)\HobbyHomesWebApp\ePortfolio\PortFolioContent\1\Assignments



2) E:\HOBBYHOMES(E-PORTFOLIO)\HobbyHomesWebApp\ActivityPostin\Images\ePortfolio\PortFolioContent\1\Assignments\Exhb_1_1.jpg







I can not see folder e-Portfolio. Can you please update your question again and what exact path you want?As per me you want 2nd path and getting first path.

Comment: hey sry i had pasted the wrong path forgotto do it while editing..and thanx anyways now it is working:)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"),("ePortfolio\\PortFolioContent\\" + Course_Id + "\\Assignments\\Exhb_" + item.PortfolioID + "_" + item.ChandidateID + ".jpg"));
```

In theory it results in the same answer that failed you previously.  In practice, it may yield a completely different answer.

There's also a recent question here (which I can't find at the moment) which highlights that sometimes Server.MapPath("~/..etc..") misbehaves on rewritten request paths.  Are you rewriting the request that is trying to form this path?

Comment: nopes m nt calling it again i wrote it like this
string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/ePortfolio/PortFolioContent/" + Course_Id + "/Assignments/Exhb_" + item.PortfolioID + "_" + item.ChandidateID + ".jpg"); earlier i ah nt placed in the folder from where it was executing so that may be problem.so now i got it working:)